# Реализовать метод расширения ToProductViewModels, который принимает перечисление продуктов из базы данных и переводит в перечисление продуктов

Tags: c#

Дан класс для хранения продукта в базе данных ProductDb:

```
public class ProductDb
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Для отображения продукта пользователю нужны не все данные, а только те, которые описаны в классе ProductViewModel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Ваша задача реализовать метод расширения ToProductViewModels, который принимает перечисление продуктов из базы данных и переводит в перечисление продуктов для отображения пользователю.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var productDb1 = new ProductDb()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Молоко",
        Cost = 120,
        Description = "Натуральное молоко из деревни",
        ImagePath = "https://lenta.gcdn.co/globalassets/1/-/10/20/65/346818_2.png?preset=fulllossywhite"
    };

    var productDb2 = new ProductDb()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Сок",
        Cost = 50,
        Description = "Среднегазированный",
        ImagePath = "test/image"
    };

    var productsDb = new List<ProductDb>
    {
        productDb1, productDb2
    };

    var productViewModels = productsDb.ToProductViewModels();

    foreach (var item in productViewModels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Cost);
    }
}
```

Не совсем понимаю какую структуру должен иметь статический метод расширения, может кто-то сможет подкинуть идею. Правильная ли структура метода в целом? Нужно ли здесь использовать this для расширения  класса ProductDb. Не понимаю как подступиться.

```
static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>ToProductViewModels(this IEnumerable<ProductDb> product)
{
    return product.Select(prod => new ProductDb())
}
```

Вот такую конструкцию выстроил, но что-то не получается это в метод расширения превратить

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> ToProductViewModels(this IEnumerable<ProductDb> product)
        {
            return product.Select(x => new ProductViewModel() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Cost = x.Cost });
}
```

Comment: `Не совсем понимаю какую структуру должен иметь статический метод расширения` - Он должен вам `IEnumerable<ProductDb>` перевести в `IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>` с сохранением всех значений каждого объекта коллекции. Обычно такое делается через так называемые мапперы (AutoMapper) например, ну а у вас, если тестовое задание, то как вы и сделали, пробигаясь по списку и каждый класс переводите. Ну, или рефлексия, где ищется свойство по имени, если совпадения есть - заполняется, тогда будет "универсальный" метод.  `Нужно ли здесь использовать this` - без него не может быть метода расширения.

Comment: `что-то не получается это в метод расширения превратить` - метод расширения может быть **только** в публичном, статичном классе.

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чем косяк, надо просто было в статический класс это все засунуть

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> ToProductViewModels(this IEnumerable<ProductDb> product)
            {
                return product.Select(x => new ProductViewModel() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Cost = x.Cost });
    }
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` - это последовательность объектов. Поэтому название параметра должно быть во множественном числе: `products`.